# Facebook's Send to Messenger Plugin Not Working on In-App Browser

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger-bot

After Continuing with your Messenger account, **the plugin doesn't work as expected when in-app browser**. You will just be presented with a white screen with a "1" in it. I've checked the url and here it is - https://m.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php?reload=https%3A%2F%2Fsocialplugin.facebook.net%2Fsend_to_messenger.php%3Fapp_id%3D7255615124546099%26channel%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fstaticxx.facebook.com%252Fx%252Fconnect%252Fxd_arbiter%252F%253Fversion%253D46%2523cb%253Dffb5aad30c3a67d4d%2526domain%253Dde18-136-158-11-115.ngrok-free.app%2526is_canvas%253Dfalse%2526origin%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fde18-136-158-11-115.ngrok-free.app%25252Ffc017cd317be54e20%2526relation%253Dparent.parent%26color%3Dblue%26container_width%3D318%26cta_text%3DGET_STARTED%26locale%3Den_US%26messenger_app_id%3D7255615124546099%26page_id%3D155078761029891%26ref%3D3Bjf4NpdsS9aSje2bgMyVn%26sdk%3Djoey%26ret%3Doptin%26act%3Dsend%26has_explicit_interaction%3D1%26hash%3DAQBL8dv7c6bnclfZuno#_=_https://m.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php?reload=https%3A%2F%2Fsocialplugin.facebook.net%2Fsend_to_messenger.php%3Fapp_id%3D7255615124546099%26channel%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fstaticxx.facebook.com%252Fx%252Fconnect%252Fxd_arbiter%252F%253Fversion%253D46%2523cb%253Dffb5aad30c3a67d4d%2526domain%253Dde18-136-158-11-115.ngrok-free.app%2526is_canvas%253Dfalse%2526origin%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fde18-136-158-11-115.ngrok-free.app%25252Ffc017cd317be54e20%2526relation%253Dparent.parent%26color%3Dblue%26container_width%3D318%26cta_text%3DGET_STARTED%26locale%3Den_US%26messenger_app_id%3D7255615124546099%26page_id%3D155078761029891%26ref%3D3Bjf4NpdsS9aSje2bgMyVn%26sdk%3Djoey%26ret%3Doptin%26act%3Dsend%26has_explicit_interaction%3D1%26hash%3DAQBL8dv7c6bnclfZuno#_=_

[image: Clicking the account confirmation button]

[image: White screen with "1"]

The expected behavior is, it's supposed to redirect me back to the /order-summary page of my website after the confirming the messenger account. The plugin works as expected when accessing my website in a regular browser